React i18n useTranslation does not load namespaces on demand
I use react-i18next backend to load my resources. The problem is i want my resources not to be loaded all at the start, but rather loaded when they are needed when used inside of t() function. For example, on startup i want to load a default namespace named "translation", and somewhere in my code when my component loads and calls t("namespace2:someText"), i want my namespace2.json to be loaded at that moment. I dont want to specify beforehand the namespaces inside the t function. I know you can do it like this useTranslation('namespace2'); t("someText"), but that is not what i want.
I want it to be automatically detected and when the namespace hasnt been loaded then to load it.
My i18n config
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

const namespaces = ['namespace1','translation', 'namespace2']

i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        debug: true,
        backend: {
            loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
        },
        ns: namespaces,
        defaultNS: 'translation',
        load: 'languageOnly',
        lng: 'en',
        // preload: ['en'],
        supportedLngs: ['en','de'],
        react: {
            useSuspense: false
        },
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
        }
    }, (err) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
    });


export default i18n;

My UI:
import './App.css';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import i18n from "./i18n";
import {useState} from "react";

function App() {
    const [showComponent, setShowComponent] = useState(false);

  const {t} = useTranslation()

  const changeLanguage = (e) => {
      i18n.changeLanguage("de")
  }

  return (
      <div>
          <div className="App">
              {t('namespace1:text2parent.text2child1', 'My text in child21(default)')}
          </div>
          <button onClick={changeLanguage}>
              Click to change lang
          </button>
          <button onClick={()=>setShowComponent(true)}>
              Click to show component
          </button>
          {
              showComponent && (
                  <div>
                      <p>
                          {t('namespace2:someText','Default text')}
                      </p>
                  </div>
              )
          }
      </div>
  );
}


Does this answer your question: Using i18next with TypeScript: How to Support Prefixed Namespace Keys in the t Function?

This question is similar to: Using i18next with TypeScript: How to Support Prefixed Namespace Keys in the t Function. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
